# Segmentation fault when printing the linked list

Tags: c, linked-list, segmentation-fault, printf

I've been reading the Stanford tutorial for linked lists. I used one of the functions which creates a list of three numbers (1,2,3). The function itself doesn't print the result, so I decided to test it myself. However, when I run it, it gives me segmentation fault.

With that being said, when I remove the function and copy the code into main, it works. Can someone please explain why the main doesn't work with the function?

This is the code that gives me segmentation fault:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

      struct node {
         int            data;
         struct node*   next;
};

struct node* BuildOneTwoThree() 

{
   struct node* head = NULL;
   struct node* second = NULL;
   struct node* third = NULL;
   head = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
   second = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
   third = malloc(sizeof(struct node));

head->data = 1;
head->next = second;
second->data = 2;
second->next = third;
third->data = 3;
third->next = NULL;

return head;

}


int main()

{
   struct node* head;
   struct node* second;
   struct node* third;
   struct node*   next;

   int data;

   BuildOneTwoThree();

   struct node* current = head;



while(current != NULL)
   {
      printf("%d ", current->data );

      current= current->next;

   }

}
```

This one works:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

      struct node {
         int            data;
         struct node*   next;
};



int main()

{

   int data;

   struct node* head = NULL;
   struct node* second = NULL;
   struct node* third = NULL;
   head = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
   second = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
   third = malloc(sizeof(struct node));

head->data = 1;
head->next = second;
second->data = 2;
second->next = third;
third->data = 3;
third->next = NULL;

   struct node* current = head;



while(current != NULL)
   {
      printf("%d ", current->data );

      current= current->next;

   }

}
```

Comment: `head = BuildOneTwoThree();`

Comment: same problem, thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the version that does not work, you are ignoring the return value of `BuildOneTwoThree`, and assigning the uninitialized local variable `head` from `main` (which is not the same as the local variable of the same name in the `BuildOneTwoThree` scope) to the variable `current`.

The printing code should thus use:

```
struct node* head = BuildOneTwoThree();
current = head;
```

instead, to make use of the `head` node allocated in `BuildOneTwoThree()`, and assign to `main`'s head pointer.